# change text link color javascript or css

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, colors

I have a menu on my website, I'm using CSS when mouseo hover on item on my menu and when clicking.

here is my menu :

```
<div id="stickyheader">
    <a href="#disco">discography</a><span class="grey"> - </span>
    <a href="#bio">biography</a><span class="grey"> - </span>
    <a href="#press">press</a><span class="grey"> - </span>
    <a href="#studio">studio</a><span class="grey"> - </span>
    <a href="#contacts">contacts</a> 
</div>
```

and my CSS for the links:

```
a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:focus, a:active {
    color: #dcdedd;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition:color 0.5s ease-in;  
    -moz-transition:color 0.5s ease-in;  
    -o-transition:color 0.5s ease-in;  
    transition:color 0.5s ease-in;
}
a:hover{
    color: red
}
```

I would like to know if there's a way using css, or javascript, when clicking on one item of my menu, to change the text color of the selected item to red, and keep the red color until choosing another item of my menu.

This need to happen only in my #stickyheader div, not on the rest of the website...

example : when I click on "Biography", biography turns into red, with the transition (0.5s ease-in), and "biography" stays red until I click on another item, and when I click on "discography", discography turns into red, and Biography return lightgray...

I can't manage to find a solution...

maybe JS ?

here is a JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/B5dYv/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#stickyheader a').on('click', function() {
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

I updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B5dYv/5/

Comment: thanks a lot @darthmaim, I've edited my jsfiddle, I have a "back to top" section after each section in my website, when clicking on back to top, is it possible to remove all colors in my menu ?
when I click on Biography, biography stays red, and when I click on back to top at the bottom of my section I would like to go back on top of my page, like it works nom, and remove all red colors in my menu, you understand what I mean ? here is my jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/B5dYv/12/

Comment: To remove all colors from the menu simply use `$(".active").removeClass("active");`

Comment: hum... it's not working... i already have $(".active").removeClass("active"); in my js no ?

Comment: You have to call it when you want to remove the colors, for example with this code: `$('.backToTop').on('click', function() { $(".active").removeClass("active"); });`

Comment: ok thanks a lot @darthmaim, I just corrected with the right class name and it works perfectly well ! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's a jquery solution:

```
$('#wrapper').on('click', 'a', function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

And the relevant css:

```
.selected
{
     color: red !important;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B5dYv/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that with jQuery :

http://jsfiddle.net/fG5Uy/2/

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#stickyheader a").click(function(){
        $("#stickyheader a").each(function(i, e){
            $(this).removeClass("selected");
        });                                  
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#stickyheader a.selected
{
    color : blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/JWkZn/

```
$('#wrapper a').click(function(){
    $('#wrapper a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});


a.active { color: red }
```